# How do I build openvpn without libpam?

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, build, pam

Since I have no root privilege to install libpam, I failed to run `./configure`. So is there any method with which I can build openvpn without libpam?

```
checking for OPENSSL_CRYPTO... yes
checking for OPENSSL_SSL... yes
checking for EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length... yes
checking for ENGINE_load_builtin_engines... yes
checking for ENGINE_register_all_complete... yes
checking for ENGINE_cleanup... yes
checking for ssl_init in -lpolarssl... no
checking for aes_crypt_cbc in -lpolarssl... no
checking for lzo1x_1_15_compress in -llzo2... no
checking for lzo1x_1_15_compress in -llzo... no
checking for PKCS11_HELPER... no
checking git checkout... yes
configure: error: libpam required but missing
```

What's more, why can't I disable libpam option?

```
[mirror@innov openvpn]$ ./configure --help | grep libpam
  --enable-pam-dlopen     dlopen libpam [default=no]
              C compiler flags for libpam
  LIBPAM_LIBS linker flags for libpam
```

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling PAM at the configuration step:

```
./configure --disable-plugin-auth-pam
```